# PHP: How can I disallow HTML content in user-generated content?

Tags: php

I run a niche social network site. I would like to disallow HTML content in user posted messages; such as embedded videos etc. what option is there in php to clean this up before I insert into the db.

Comment: Are you using a CMS, if so which one.

Answer (score 14):

There are three basic solutions:

1. Strip all HTML tags from the post. In PHP you can do this using the [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.
2. Encode all the characters, so that if a user types `<b>hello</b>` it shows up as `&lt;b&gt;hello&lt;/b&gt;` in the HTML, or `<b>hello</b>` on the page itself. In PHP this is the [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function. (Note: in this situation you would generally store the content in the database as-is, and use htmlspecialchars wherever you output the content.)
3. Use a HTML sanitizer such as [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). This allows users to use certain HTML formatting such as bold/italic, but blocks malicious Javascript and any other tags you wish (i.e. `<object>` in your case). You may or may not wish to do this before storing in the database, but you must *always* do it before output in either case.

Comment: Thanks.  Are those `either / or`, or `and` suggestions?

Comment: @JDelage Either/or, except if you use `strip_tags` you should also use `htmlspecialchars` to encode any leftover greater/less than symbols as well as quotes and ampersands.

Comment: If you want to keep the structure of the input (e.g. HTML tables and lists) you have to implement whitelist based filtering. Note that because you may later want to modify your whitelist, you **should not filter before storing the data into dabase** but every time you're rendering the response to the client. Only that way you can remove some element or attribute from your whitelist when it's later found dangerous. If you don't need to support complex structures, you have to decide if you want to display disallowed content as plain text or simply removed. You can safely just *encode* anything.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen fair points, I've updated my answer. There are arguments for and against sanitising before storing in the database - yes you can "lose data" but often that doesn't matter. But you must always sanitise on output.

Comment: The reason I strongly recommend not sanitizing your input before storing it is the same reasoning as with whitelist filtering; if you have a bug / bad feature in your sanitizing filter you'll end up losing data unrecovably. If you just *encode* all incoming data as binary data (instead of not encoding it at all which results in injection attacks), you'll be fine in all cases.

Comment: For example, say you have a number input, should you throw away user input `1,234,567.00`? If your sanitizing drops all characters not matching regex `[0-9]` you'll end up storing a wrong number. And if you simply disallow that input because it doesn't match regex `^[0-9]+$` the user experience is pretty bad when the form cannot be submitted or submission fails. The cases where you can be absolutely sure that the user input is bad are pretty rare – the rest can be just corner cases that you don't *yet* handle correctly.

Comment: Yes, that is a case where it does matter. There are many cases where it doesn't. In OP's case of HTML there's no harm in removing some tags even if you allow them later. If those old posts don't have the extra formatting that's fine, in fact it's probably beneficial that they don't magically change in the future.

Comment: Yes, having data as stable as possible in the long run is part of user experience, too, and shouldn't be ignored. I meant the number field example as the basic case where many people would assume that "you cannot possibly have a wrong sanitizing filter here so we can filter before DB". Full HTML input is obviously much more complex case which is why I'd avoid trying to filter it before storing the verbatim user input. Of course, that requires you keeping track which database columns contain untrusted input but you should do that anyway because *all* user input should be treated as untrusted.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the **[`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)** function.